# Section open right in scrbook

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, koma-script, double-sided, scrbook

Using `scrbook`, I would like sections to open on a new odd page, like chapters do. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `\cleardoublepage` to the action of `\section`.

No packages:

```
\long\expandafter\def\expandafter\section\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\cleardoublepage\section}
```

Shorter:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\section{\cleardoublepage}
```

Note: the `\section` command has (in the standard classes and also in the KoMa-script classes) a definition *without* arguments. The arguments are absorbed by other macros called by it.

If you want to respect the `openany` or `openright` option, then `\cleardoublepage` is not the correct command. Thus

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto\section{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}
\makeatother
```

should be used.

The "no package" version of this one might be

```
\makeatletter
\toks0={\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}
\toks2=\expandafter{\section}
\long\edef\section{\the\toks0 \the\toks2 }
\makeatother
```

Comment: “Note: the `\section` command has … in the KoMa-script [sic!] … a definition _without_ arguments.” That’s not fully true anymore since KOMA-Script version 3.10: With some options for the class key `headings` in the optional argument of all heading commands the keys `head` and `tocentry` are possible. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Speravir The "user level" syntax for `\section` shows an optional argument; but the real implementation is always of the form `\newcommand\section{\@startsection{...}...}`: the optional argument (or the *-version) is absorbed by `\@startsection` or better, to go into more depth, by `\@sect`.

Comment: @egreg Suppose I've defined `\section{Appendix}`, taking into account that "the \section command has ... a definition without arguments" how can I make the following command work: `\preto{\section{Appendix}}{\setcounter{secnumdepth{0}}`?. (I'm using the article class).

Comment: There is a typo en my previous comment, it should read: `\preto{\section{Appendix}}{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}}`.

Comment: I ended up doing `\newcommand*{\appheading}{\section{Appendix}}\preto{\appheading}{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine `\section` to add `\cleardoublepage` or `\clearpage` (depending on whether `openright` or `openany` is active) so as to behave as `\chapter`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{%
\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ \@plus 1fil}%
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section\nobreak}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test Section Two}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This one is quite interesting, as it mimicks the behavior set for `chapter`. I like that.

Comment: @ℝaphink **egreg** has added the same in his edited answer.

Comment: Yes. I chose his answer because it's got several options.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\let\mySection\section
\renewcommand\section{\cleardoublepage\mySection}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
text
\section{bar}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite straightforward…